# Determine whether the given formula represents an inner product or not .

Tags: linear-algebra

**Problem**

In the linear space of all real polynomials , determine whether or not $(f,g)$ is an inner product if$(f,g)$ is defined by the formula given .

$a) (f,g) = f(1)g(1)$

$b)(f,g) = |\int_{0}^{1} f(t)g(t) dt|$

$c) (f,g)= \int_{0}^{1} f'(t)g'(t) dt$

$d) (f,g) = (\int_{0}^{1} f(t) dt)(\int_{0}^{1} g(t) dt)$

**Attempt**
$a,c,d$ represents inner product as all are *commutative,distributive, homogeneous and positive*

$b$ is not homogeneous .So it does not represents inner product.

In solving $c)$ i have assumed functions to be continuous ( don't know whether this assumption is valid or not.)

Is my attempt correct?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated

Comment: You have polynomials...

Answer (score 1):

Recall that in order to be an inner product, $(.|.)$ has to be :

$\cdot$ Commutative : $\forall f,g\in\mathbb{R}[X],(f|g)=(g|f)$

$\cdot$ Linear with respect to the first (or the second) argument : $\forall f,g,h\in\mathbb{R}[X], \forall \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, (f+\lambda h|g)=(f|g)+\lambda(h|g)$ (This is what you call "distributive")

$\cdot$ Positive and homogenous : $\forall f\in\mathbb{R}, (f|f)\geq0 \text{ and} (f|f)=0 \Leftrightarrow f=0$

Now :

a) is not an inner product because it is not homogenous :
$$(f|f)=0 \Leftrightarrow f(1)^2=0 \Leftrightarrow f(1)=0$$
Which is not equivalent to $f=0_{\mathbb{R}[X]}$ (take X-1 as a counter-example)

b) nether : it is not symetrical with respect to the first argument (nor the second), due to the fact that $|a+b|=|a|+|b| is false in general.

c) nether ; it is not homogenous :
$$(f|f)=0 \Leftrightarrow \forall x\in(0,1),f'(x)=0 \Leftrightarrow f \text{ is constant on (0,1)}$$
Which is not equivalent to $f=0_{\mathbb{R}[X]}$ (take f(X)=1 as a counter-example)

d) nether, because it is not homogenous :
$$(f|f)=0 \Leftrightarrow \left(\int_0^1f(x)\text{d}x\right)^2=0 \Leftrightarrow \int_0^1f(x)\text{d}x=0$$
Which is not equivalent to $f=0_{\mathbb{R}[X]}$ (take f(x)=1-2x as a counter-example).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't using$ (f|f)=0$ condition. I was only using $(f|f)>0$. Now i can see.

Comment: All the other properties in a,c,and d are satisfied